# NGinx - rewrite, proxy_pass - Apache Tomcat

Tags: nginx, tomcat

```
location /en/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    #добавляем параметр через &
    rewrite ^/en/(.*)?(.*)$ http://www.mysite.ru/$1?$2&locale=en break;

    #добавляем параметр через ?
    rewrite ^/en/(.*)$ http://www.mysite.ru/$1?locale=en break;

    #направляем к томкату
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    break;
}
```

так вот, захожу на сайт .../en/ меня редиректит 302 на .../?&locale=en

Подскажите пжл. Спасибо.

А хотелось бы так:

```
url: ..../en/somepage/page2 -> к томкату приходит: .../somepage/page2?locale=en

url: ..../en/somepage/page2?a=b -> к томкату приходит: .../somepage/page2?a=b&locale=en
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location /en/ {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  rewrite ^/en/(.*)(\?.*)?$ /$1?$args&locale=en;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

Ошибся в урле, исправил.

Comment: /en/city редиректит на /city :(

Comment: В томкате нет редиректа. Редиректит во всех браузерах.(

Comment: Странно, редиректа в правилах нет совсем...

Comment: Ошибся. 500 internal error (забыл перезапустить nginx)

Comment: А в логах что? Может быть надо добавить break?

Comment: добавил в конец break, теперь томкат выдаёт 404

Comment: Получилось?

Answer (score 0):

Получилось. Оказывается у меня томкат редиректил.

А в 
rewrite ^/en/(.*)(?.*)?$ /$1?$args&locale=en;

не будет так:
/en/msk -> к томкату /msk?&locale=en?

Comment: Инструкция
    rewrite ^/en/(.*)(\?.*)?$ /$1?$args&locale=en;
переведет /en/msk в /en/msk?&locale=en, но это никак не отразится на работе

Comment: т.е. последовательность ?& это нормально?

Comment: Вполне :) Это корректно с любой точки зрения, кроме, конечно, "эстетической", но пользователь этого все равно не видит )